# React Hook Form - Resetting "isDirty" without clearing form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Basically what the title says. When I submit the form I'm checking if the login is successful, if not it displays a message. However, when the user starts to type I want this message to go away.

Kinda assumed `isDirty` would be cleared once the form was submitted, but it remains dirty. I can call `reset` from the `onSubmit`, but that will clear the forms' content - which I don't want.

Ideas?

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can send a new set of values to the [reset](https://react-hook-form.com/api/#reset). Since you do receive a set of values in the submit handler, you could connect both functionalities in the following way:

```
const {reset, handleSubmit, formState} = useForm();
const {isDirty} = formState;

const handleFormSubmit = (values) =>
{
    //This would be the call where you post your info
    fetch('google.com')
    .then(response => console.log('response', response))
    .finally(() => reset(values));
}
```

Notice the `reset(values)` in the example above, which will reset your form to the values it tried to submit. Thus, rendering `isDirty` back to false.

This is a rather common need in forms that do not reload or redirect after sending the information, so I assume they will eventually create a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Warning: `reset` also changes the `id` from the fields `useFieldArray`, so will cause remounting of those components (only some use-cases will be affected).  It's discussed more [here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/3719).  The answers below (`reset({}, { keepValues: true });`) don't seem to have this issue.

Answer (score 13):

resetting in a useEffect() will work, but useEffect() should not be used for such things. see all the discussions around react 18 and useEffect() running twice.

just call

`reset({}, { keepValues: true });`

in your handleSubmit function at the end. no need to provide all values if you just want to keep the current ones.

Comment: This causes another problem and sets the form to the previous defaults value. Also tried adding `keepValues` but no effect.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to this thread and posted by Charlie-Hua, we both solved this by:
https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/3097

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isSubmitSuccessful) {
      reset({}, { keepValues: true });
    }
  }, [isSubmitSuccessful, reset]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To reset the `isDirty` state without interfering with the form's values or default values, one example would be (being explicit):

```
reset(undefined, {keepValues: true, keepDirty: false, keepDefaultValues: false});
```

**Example with `React.useEffect()` hook**:

I want to keep the submitted `name` and `filter` values and the ability to reset to the original `defaultValues`, while resetting `isDirty`:

```
const { reset, formState: { isSubmitSuccessful } } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    filter: "",
    category: "",
  }
});

React.useEffect(() => {
  if(isSubmitSuccessful) {
    reset(undefined, {keepValues: true, keepDirty: false, keepDefaultValues: false});
  }
}, [isSubmitSuccessful, reset]);
```

The [useForm Documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/reset) explains under **props** the different options available for `reset()`. They can also be referenced in the project's [TypeScript Declaration](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/src/types/form.ts#L152-L162)

**Infered type:**

```
const reset: (values?: any, keepStateOptions?: Partial<{
    keepDirtyValues: boolean;
    keepErrors: boolean;
    keepDirty: boolean;
    keepValues: boolean;
    keepDefaultValues: boolean;
    keepIsSubmitted: boolean;
    keepTouched: boolean;
    keepIsValid: boolean;
    keepSubmitCount: boolean;
}> | undefined) => void
```

Answer (score 1):

to set the current state as not dirty you should reset, send false to other params and send the current state as values:

```
reset(watch(), { keepValues: false, keepDirty: false, keepDefaultValues: false });
```